# BigQuery - concatenate array of strings for each row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

Given this input:

```
Row     id      app_date    inventor   country
1       id_1    01-15-2022  Steve       US
                            Ashley      US
2       id_2    03-16-2011  Pete        US
                            Jamie       US
                            Mary        FR
```

I need to concatenate `inventor` strings for each `id`, like so:

```
Row     id      app_date    inventors   
1       id_1    01-15-2022  Steve, Ashley
2       id_2    03-16-2011  Pete, Jamie, Mary
```

Following [this example](https://bigquery-lab.dimensions.ai/queries/03/), I managed to get here:

```
Row     id      app_date    inventor
1       id_1    01-15-2022  Steve
                            Ashley
2       id_2    03-16-2011  Pete
                            Jamie
                            Mary
```

using

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT "id_1" AS id, "01-15-2022" as app_date,
    [STRUCT("Steve" as name, "EN" as country),
     STRUCT("Ashley", "EN")]
       AS inventor
  UNION ALL SELECT "id_2", "03-16-2011",
    [STRUCT("Pete", "EN"), STRUCT("Jamie", "EN"), STRUCT("Mary", "FR")]),

    res as (
        SELECT id, app_date,
            (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT name FROM UNNEST(inventor))) AS inventors
            FROM sample
        )

SELECT id, app_date, inventors
FROM res
```

that is, the second to last step of that example. Final step seems like `ARRAY_TO_STRING` on the `inventors` column, but I'm getting a `No matching signature for function ARRAY_TO_STRING for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>` error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(inventor), 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ', ') FROM t.inventor) inventors
FROM sample t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to accomplish this with `ARRAY_TO_STRING`? I need to handle possible `NULL`s by providing explicit values.