# BigQuery - concatenate array of strings for each row with `null`s

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

*This is a clarification/follow-up on the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486978/bigquery-concatenate-array-of-strings-for-each-row) where I didn't specify the requirement for null values.*

Given this input:

```
Row     id      app_date    inventor.name   inventor.country
1       id_1    01-15-2022  Steve           US
                            Ashley          US
2       id_2    03-16-2011  Pete            US
                            <null>          US
                            Mary            FR
```

I need to extract `name` from `inventor` struct and concatenate them for each `id`, like so:

```
Row     id      app_date    inventors   
1       id_1    01-15-2022  Steve, Ashley
2       id_2    03-16-2011  Pete, ^, Mary
```

Note custom filling for `null` value - which, to me, seems like it means I need to use [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#converting_arrays_to_strings) specifically that supports this.

The [closest example I found](https://bigquery-lab.dimensions.ai/queries/03/) doesn't work with `null`s. How can one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(inventor), 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(IFNULL(name, '^'), ', ') FROM t.inventor) inventors
FROM sample t
```

with output

[image]